How to remove the first character till the space in powershell
write-output $devtags2
2 text1
10 text3
5 text2
7 text4

Remove the first characters and print only the text
text1
text3
text2
text4

used the remove function but it is showing
Cannot find an overload for "Remove" and the argument count: "2".
At line:11 char:1
+ $devtags3 = $devtags2.Remove(0,3)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest


I’m voting to close this question because no evidence of the author having tried to do it themselves.

you can see the error message which I'm getting and if you know anything on powershell you can answer. @AlanB

What is $devtags2.GetType()?


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


$devtags2 is presumably an array - and the Array.Remove() method only takes one parameter argument (the element value to be removed), hence the error message.
To invoke Remove on each string value stored in the array, use ForEach-Object:
$devtags2 = @(
  '2 text1'
  '10 text3'
  '5 text2'
  '7 text4'
)

$devtags2 |ForEach-Object -MemberName Remove -ArgumentList 0,3

The result of which would be:
ext1
text3
ext2
ext4

As you can see, this had the unfortunate effect of swallowing the t in text from every string that only had 1 leading digit followed by a space.
A better approach would be to use the -replace regex operator to remove everything up to and including the first chunk of whitespace in the string:
$devtags2 -replace '^\S*\s+'

The regular expression ^\S*\s+ describes a string where:

^ - at the start of each string
\S* - match 0 or more non-whitespace characters (like 2 or 10)
\s+ - match 1 or more whitespace characters (like the   between 2 and text1)

Since we didn't supply a substitute string, the leading characters will simply be removed, and we end up with the following results instead:
text1
text3
text2
text4

